# Invalid syntax on status bar, despite code working fine

Tags: python, sublimetext

Code below works fine, but for the line:

```py
print(f"Some text {args}, some other text {key_words}, {len(key_words)}")
```

the linter show invalid syntax and always highlights the line:

```
[E] Invalid syntax, flake8(ok)
```

Tried to auto-format the code.

```py
import keyword


def contains_keyword(*args):
    key_words = []
    for item in args:
        if keyword.iskeyword(item):
            key_words.append(item)
    if len(key_words) > 0:
        print(f"Lista {args}, din care {key_words}, {len(key_words)}")
        return True
    return False

contains_keyword('is', 'def', 'str1', 'str2', 'str3', "return", "for")
```

Expect no syntax errors.

[image: Error message]

Comment: Is your linter targeting Python 3.6 syntax? Your linter doesn't seem to understand f-strings.

Comment: Try to remove _flake8_, and install it in python3. `pip uninstall flake8` followed by `pip3 install flake8`.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I ended up by removing and re-installing flake8 as Dinko Pehar suggested.